# Access the a child of a GameObject through a script that is assigned to it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem in making a little game in Unity 5. I have a prefab (named "Controller") and it is instantiated two times in the game. This prefab has a script attached to it, and also has 4 children of type GameObject. How can i access a child to the clone that it is instantiated? I need to change it's layer to Ignore Raycast if a button is pressed, but i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it assigning your instance to a GameObject:

```
GameObject clon = Instantiate (Resources.Load("MyInstanceObject")) as GameObject;

clon.transform.FindChild("Mychildname").gameobject.layer = index;
```

or too if you know your child index:

```
clon.transform.GetChild(index).gameobject.layer = index;
```

Comment: Thank you! That works too, but i found another solution. I didn't know that is a script is attached to a prefab, when it is instantiated you can access the clone's GameObject by typing gameObject.FindChild() (in my case).